# Sending mail to recipients of different mails sent earlier

Tags: gmail

So I recently sent some emails to different people not being in my address book. Now, however, I'd like to send one (the exact same one) mail to all of them. Can I somehow check all the messages in my "Sent" box and extract the emails so that I can later paste it when creating a new mail I want to send to all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, apparently there's no easy fix for that. After all, I just downloaded all the messages in .eml format, merged them to one text file and coded a Python script to run through the file and extract them for me.